# Get count of custom post type created by current user

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, count

I'm trying to get the count of published posts in a custom post type for the current user (to display on a profile page).

I found this here on the forums:

```
<?php
global $wp_query;
$curauth = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
$post_count = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_author = '" . $curauth->ID . "' AND post_type = 'user_video' AND post_status = 'publish'");
?>
```

But, it's just giving me a big fat ZERO even though there are definitely published posts of that type. What am I doing wrong and is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Did you try COUNT(ID)?

Comment: I had not, but I just tried it and it didn't work still.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm posting a new answer because I found this thread while searching for the same thing and the solutions here weren't optimal.

The `post_type` argument can be a **string** or an **array** of post types.

```
function custom_count_posts_by_author($user_id, $post_type = array('post', 'page', 'custom_post_type'))
{
    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => $post_type,
        'author'         => $user_id,
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1
    );

    $query = new WP_Query($args);

    return $query->found_posts;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest using `get_posts()` instead of `query_posts()` for your purpose.

> To create secondary listings (for example, a list of related posts at the bottom of the page, or a list of links in a sidebar widget), try making a new instance of [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) or use [get_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts). [[source]](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Secondary_Loops)

It also looks simpler now :)

```
echo count( get_posts( array( 
    'post_type' => 'user_video', 
    'author'    => get_current_user_id(), 
    'nopaging'  => true, // display all posts
) ) );
```

Answer (score 2):

OK, after more Googleing, this seems to work without having to use MySQL and dive into the database directly:

```
<?php 
        $authorid = get_current_user_id();
        query_posts(array( 
            'post_type' => 'user_video',
            'author' => $authorid,
        ) ); 
            $count = 0;
            while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
                $count++; 
            endwhile;
            echo $count;
        wp_reset_query();
    ?>
```

Comment: Thanks @MichalMau for the valuable info! This was really helpful.

Comment: This function is very inefficient because it loops through the results to update the count, while you could just get the posts count using WP_Query.

Comment: Very true. I wrote this answer long ago, before I really understood wp_query.

Comment: I posted a new answer for people landing here :)

Answer (score 2):

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/count_user_posts

```
<?php $user_post_count = count_user_posts( $userid , $post_type ); ?>
```

Comment: Can you please add an explanation **why** this is helpful - thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In authors profile for me works great this (ait-dir-item is custom post type name)

```
<?php  
$idecko = get_the_author_meta( 'ID' );
echo count_user_posts( $idecko, 'ait-dir-item' ); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare $wpdb as global as well, and use its prefix method.

```
<?php
global $wp_query, $wpdb;
$curauth = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
$post_count = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."posts WHERE post_author = '" . $curauth->ID . "' AND post_type = 'user_video' AND post_status = 'publish'");
?>
```

Comment: Hmmm, still not doing it. Is there a better method than this? I literally copied and pasted the first snippet from another answer, so I'm open to alternative ideas if you have them.

Comment: Put the whole query in a variable, die that out and take it to mysql workbench at this point then.  I'd start with just Select * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'user_video', finding an author and then working backwards from there.  Can you post what the query looks like here too after you echo it?

Comment: @AndrewBartel It's easier to parse visually using [this formatting](http://pastebin.com/1Hr4ujkw). You only need prefix for non-standard tables and no need to concatenate the string if using double-quotes.

Comment: Ah, thanks @brasofilo.  Learn something new every day.